# What is the best way to update local database to twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

I am currently making a rails app that will search #barcampmlk2 #{thesessionname} +1 from twitter. The app needs to update the local database that will count how many user voted +1 for the session.

I use jnunemaker/twitter

Now , I don't want to count how many user +1 each time page load from twitter. How am I going to do that? I can't figure out the since_id of the twitter, is it unix epoch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The since_id is not a UNIX epoch timestamp. It is a unique id associated with the state any given search result. You must save the since_id and send it with a subsequent search query. Twitter will then use it to calculate what is the appropriate response.

See [Twitter API Wiki](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554756/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3a-search), section *Refreshing Search Results*, for details.